# After reloading page animation fps is changing every time

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, frontend, web-frontend

There are two pages: 'index' and 'about'. The second page has an animation: [link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwz622xvx7)

The problem is: on local version, when I go to 'index' and then return back to 'about', animation fps is changing:

Opened About for the first time:

**52.9 fps**

[image]

Went to Index:

**41.0 fps**

[image]

Back to About:

**29.5 fps**

[image]

Can't understand what is the problem. The project is on Vue

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up in the console:

```
Too many active WebGL contexts
```

I am guessing it's not a good practice to create a new renderer and redo all the work for each mount?

I tried to keep the component alive and the problem is gone.

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view/>
</keep-alive>
```

Or you could try to move the renderer up to the parent component and reuse it, rather than creating a new one for each mount.

Btw, try the extension [PixiJS Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pixijs-devtools/aamddddknhcagpehecnhphigffljadon), it's good for PIXI debugging. It also shows that every time you click on "About", a new PIXI container is created. With the solution above, there will only be one throughout user interactions.

reference: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2233